# cronscheduledroutepolicy not working as expected in switchyard

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, switchyard

I am trying to implement cronscheduledroutepolicy in camel route and it is not working as expected. I am expecting switchyard Route to stop and start at cron trigger. I had added routePolicyRef="customRoutePolicy" and autoStartup="false" attributes in route definition.

logs:

```
23:07:01,530 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment Thunderhead-POC-PDF-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
23:07:01,558 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Thunderhead-POC-PDF-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar (runtime-name: Thunderhead-POC-PDF-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) in 30ms
23:07:01,559 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Thunderhead-POC-PDF-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" (runtime-name: "Thunderhead-POC-PDF-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")
23:07:01,657 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment Thunderhead-POC-PDF-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
23:07:01,716 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: Thunderhead-POC-PDF-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
23:07:01,718 INFO  [org.switchyard] (MSC service thread 1-4) Deploying SwitchYard application 'Thunderhead-POC-PDF-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
23:07:01,720 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment Thunderhead-POC-PDF-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
23:07:01,764 INFO  [org.switchyard] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting SwitchYard service
23:07:01,768 INFO  [org.apache.camel.management.ManagementStrategyFactory] (MSC service thread 1-4) JMX enabled.
23:07:01,771 INFO  [org.switchyard.common.camel.SwitchYardCamelContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Apache Camel 1.1.1-p5-redhat-1 (CamelContext: camel-33) is starting
23:07:01,805 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter] (MSC service thread 1-4) Loaded 181 type converters
23:07:01,814 INFO  [org.switchyard.common.camel.SwitchYardCamelContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Total 0 routes, of which 0 is started.
23:07:01,814 INFO  [org.switchyard.common.camel.SwitchYardCamelContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Apache Camel 1.1.1-p5-redhat-1 (CamelContext: camel-33) started in 0.043 seconds
23:07:01,967 INFO  [org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool] (MSC service thread 1-4) Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: MSC service thread 1-4
23:07:01,978 INFO  [org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
23:07:01,979 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (MSC service thread 1-4) Quartz Scheduler v.1.8.5 created.
23:07:01,979 INFO  [org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore] (MSC service thread 1-4) RAMJobStore initialized.
23:07:01,980 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (MSC service thread 1-4) Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v1.8.5) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-33' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.


23:07:01,980 INFO  [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] (MSC service thread 1-4) Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-33' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
23:07:01,980 INFO  [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] (MSC service thread 1-4) Quartz scheduler version: 1.8.5
23:07:01,980 INFO  [org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzComponent] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Quartz scheduler: DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-33
23:07:01,981 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (MSC service thread 1-4) Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-33_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
23:07:01,982 INFO  [org.apache.camel.routepolicy.quartz.ScheduledRoutePolicy] (MSC service thread 1-4) Scheduled trigger: triggerGroup-route19.trigger-START-route19 for action: START on route route19
23:07:02,001 INFO  [org.switchyard.common.camel.SwitchYardCamelContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Skipping starting of route route19 as its configured with autoStartup=false
23:07:02,153 INFO  [org.switchyard.common.camel.SwitchYardCamelContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Route: direct:{urn:com.example.switchyard:Thunderhead-POC-PDF:1.0}ESBService started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://%7Burn:com.example.switchyard:Thunderhead-POC-PDF:1.0%7DESBService]
23:07:02,217 INFO  [org.switchyard.common.camel.SwitchYardCamelContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Route: V1CamelJmsBindingModel/ESBService@jms1#-275801100 started and consuming from: Endpoint[jms://queue:Document.Eu.In.Deferred?connectionFactory=%23ConnectionFactory&replyTo=Document.Eu.Out.Result]
23:07:02,319 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "Thunderhead-POC-PDF-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" with deployment "Thunderhead-POC-PDF-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

Iam trying similar to this [Throttling based on time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228786/throttling-based-on-time-interval.i) need to pick messages from queue only during cron trigger,but the attached component starts listening the queue once deployment is done.
can you please tell me what might be the issue?

Camel Route:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route streamCache="true" routePolicyRef="customRoutePolicy" autoStartup="false">
         <from uri="switchyard://ESBService" />
        <log message="Header is: ${headers.ResponseType}" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${headers.ResponseType} == 'XMLANDPDF'</simple>
                <bean ref="CreateStub" method="setAttachmentInHeader()" />
                <to uri="xslt:xslt/create-response.xslt" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <bean ref="CreateStub" method="setAttachmentInBody()" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <log message="Response is: ${body}" />
    </route>
</routes>
```

Route Policy:

```
package com.example.switchyard.Thunderhead_POC_PDF;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.camel.routepolicy.quartz.CronScheduledRoutePolicy;
public class MyRoutePolicy{

    @Produces @Named("customRoutePolicy")
    public static CronScheduledRoutePolicy  createRoutePolicy ()
    {
        CronScheduledRoutePolicy policy=new CronScheduledRoutePolicy(); 
        policy.setRouteStartTime("0 27 18 ? * *");
        policy.setRouteStopGracePeriod(10000);
        policy.setRouteStartTime("0 29 18 ? * *");
        return policy;
    } 

}
```

Switchyard xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sy:switchyard xmlns:camel="urn:switchyard-component-camel:config:1.1" xmlns:jms="urn:switchyard-component-camel-jms:config:1.1" xmlns:sca="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/opencsa/sca/200912" xmlns:sy="urn:switchyard-config:switchyard:1.1" name="Thunderhead-POC-PDF" targetNamespace="urn:com.example.switchyard:Thunderhead-POC-PDF:1.0">
  <sca:composite name="Thunderhead-POC-PDF" targetNamespace="urn:com.example.switchyard:Thunderhead-POC-PDF:1.0">
    <sca:component name="Component">
      <camel:implementation.camel>
        <camel:xml path="route.xml"/>
      </camel:implementation.camel>
      <sca:service name="ESBService">
        <sy:interface.esb inputType="java.lang.String" outputType="java.io.InputStream"/>
      </sca:service>
    </sca:component>
    <sca:service name="ESBService" promote="Component/ESBService">
      <sy:interface.esb inputType="java.lang.String" outputType="java.io.InputStream"/>
      <jms:binding.jms name="jms1">
        <jms:contextMapper includes="sourceSystemID.*,ResponseType.*"/>
        <jms:queue>Document.Eu.In.Deferred</jms:queue>
        <jms:connectionFactory>#ConnectionFactory</jms:connectionFactory>
        <jms:replyTo>Document.Eu.Out.Result</jms:replyTo>
      </jms:binding.jms>
    </sca:service>
  </sca:composite>
</sy:switchyard>
```